# How do I pass a structure as an argument to a function for error checking in C?

Tags: c, function, structure

**General description of code:-**

```
     It is a simple program in C using structures to get the input from    
     the user and print the output.Both input and output are defined as    
     separate functions in separate files. Additional user defined error 
     header file is created for error handling which checks error of C 
     function calls, 'malloc' in this case.
```

**Environment: Linux, OS: fedora**

**error**

```
    input.c: In function ‘input’:
    input.c:17:8: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘error’
      error(*val, -1, "malloc");    //error because of this line //usage error(int return_variable, value, "func_name")
            ^
    In file included from input.c:3:0:
    error.h:7:6: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct Eq’
     void error(int val, int ret, char* func_name)
          ^~~~~
    make: *** [Makefile:10: input.o] Error 1
```

**main.c**

```
//********* headers **********//
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//********** structure *********//
struct Eq
{
    int *x;
    int *y;
};

//********** Function prototypes ***********//

struct Eq* input();             
int output(struct Eq*);


//*********** Main function *************//
int main()
{
    struct Eq* num;

    num = input();          //takes user input, returns to num

    output(num);            //prints the output, num passed as arg.

    return 0;
}
```

**input.c**  input function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"error.h"                   //user defined header file

//********** structure *********//
struct Eq
{
    int *x;
    int *y;
};

struct Eq* input()
{
    struct Eq *val;

    val = (struct Eq*)malloc(sizeof(struct Eq));
    error(*val, -1, "malloc");          //error because of this line    //usage error(int return_variable, value, "func_name")

    val->x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
// *val->x = -1;                    //!! try changing this and func below to invoke error function !!
    error(*val->x, -1, "malloc");           //no errors because of this

    val->y = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    error(*val->y, -1, "malloc");           //no errors because of this

    printf("Enter the value of x:");
    scanf("%d", val->x);

    printf("Enter the value of y:");
    scanf("%d", val->y);

    return val;
}
```

**output.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//********** structure *********//
struct Eq
{
        int *x;
        int *y;
};

int output(struct Eq *num)
{
        printf("value of x=%d\n",*num->x);
        printf("value of y=%d\n",*num->y);

        return 0;
}
```

**error.h** Error Handler header file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void error(int, int, char*);

void error(int val, int ret, char* func_name)
{
        if(val == ret)
        {
                switch(ret)
                {
                        case 0:
                                printf("fatal error at %s, return 0\n", func_name);
                                exit(1);

                        case -1:
                                printf("fatal error at %s, return -1\n", func_name);
                                exit(1);
                }
        }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact text of the error that the compiler produces?

Comment: malloc returns a null pointer on failure, and for error checking you dereference it first?

Comment: also the first argument of `error` is `int`, not `struct Eq` according to your comment

Comment: Thanks for the update, but images of text are not acceptable on this site. Please replace the image with the text of the error.

Comment: Yes the argument is not struct, so what changes can be done to the error handler so that structs can be passed.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` returns a null pointer on failure, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/). Your error function has to take a pointer, as you can't derefernce a null pointer, and then check whether it is `NULL`. Something like this:

```
void error(void *ptr, char *func_name)
{
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {     
        printf("fatal error at %s, return NULL\n", func_name);
        exit(1);
    }
}

// call like this:
error(val, "malloc"); // after val = malloc...
error(val->x, "malloc"); // after val->x = malloc...
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but what changes  can I make to the error.h to include check for null.
I do agree Ideally  it should have been:-
if(!val)
{
   perror("malloc");
   exit(1);
}
something along these lines. However my goal is to create a function which can do this.

Comment: Hi thanks for the code, what if I have to use the same function for non pointer returning errors. I was looking forward to make something a bit generalized.